registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()) in fragment not working correctly
I use registerForActivityResult to request permissions in a fragment as follows
    private var mediaLauncher =
    registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()) { permissions ->
        Log.d("log", "permissions: $permissions")

    }


    private fun requireExternalPermission() {
    val arrayPermission = arrayOf(
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    )
    mediaLauncher.launch(arrayPermission)
}

and the problem is that when I run the requireExternalPermission() function, it returns the result without waiting for the user to click allow or not.

What API level is the device you are testing on? Those permissions aren't granted to any app on API 34 and higher devices due to the change to granular storage permissions.

The problem is that you declined permission before. that's why the Android system automatically delegated the result to the launcher. To test it again, you can uninstall the app and try again.

You should change your registerForActivityResult like this
private var mediaLauncher =registerForActivityResult(RequestPermission()) 
{ isGranted: Boolean ->
    if (isGranted) {
        // Permission is granted. Continue the action or workflow in your
        // app.
    } else {
        // Explain to the user that the feature is unavailable because the
        // feature requires a permission that the user has denied. At the
        // same time, respect the user's decision. Don't link to system
        // settings in an effort to convince the user to change their
        // decision.
    }
}

for more details refer Here
